# Writing text from div class to input class

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello i need write text from div class to input class.

This is my code:

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

lol = input("Click to print div class text on console...")

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("<any link to verification code")

# This is xpath of div class.
verification_code = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")))
# And this is xpath of input class.
verification_code = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input")))
```

So i need get text from div class and send it to input class.

Comment: can you give the URL as you mentioned the XPath

Comment: @YaDavMaNish it is not possible for now because you need do another things to reach this page and xpaths.

Comment: So can I take any URL from side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `.get_attribute()`,

```
# This is xpath of div class.
verification_code = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")))

input_text = verification_code.get_attribute("innerText")

# And this is xpath of input class.
verification_code = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input")))

verification_code.send_Keys(input_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Getting verification code
verification_code = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xxxxx"))).text
# Input
Passing_verification_code = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xxxxx"))).send_keys(verification_code)
```